# Adding scale to my pipeline showing me weird error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, pipeline, data-preprocessing

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
my_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("scale", StandardScaler),
    ("preprocessor", preprocessor),
    ("model", model)
])

my_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

**Raising the error** `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'fit'`.

When I run the code without scaling it shows no error but with the scaling, it shows a weird (for me) error.

So my questions are:

- How can I properly add a scale to my pipeline?
- Why the variable my_pipeline is a pandas object?

**Edit**

```
#Creation of imputer to deal with missing value for numerical_cols
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
numerical_transformer = SimpleImputer(strategy="mean")

#Creation of pipe to deal with categorical value and their missing value
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

categorical_cols = [cname for cname in X.columns if data[cname].nunique() < 10 and data[cname].dtype == "object"]
numerical_cols = [cname for cname in X.columns if data[cname].dtypes != "object"]
numerical_cols.remove("PassengerId")

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ("onehot", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
])

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
    ("num", numerical_transformer, numerical_cols),
    ("cat", categorical_transformer, categorical_cols)
])
```

- The error is line 12 at `my_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)`

Comment: What is preprocessor ? Can you show it ? The AttributeError happens at what line ?

Comment: I guess you're missing parenthesis to instantiate the `StandardScaler()` instance in your pipeline

Comment: Wow, Thanks was struggling with this error for a long time already.